# Создание базы данных и таблицы в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Установил я MySQL Workbench, ввел запрос `CREATE DATABASE python_mysql;`. После этого нигде новой базы данных я не увидел, хотя написано, что она была успешно создана. Вместо этого есть схемы (SCHEMAS), в которых располагаются таблицы и к которым можно обращаться как к базам данных из Python или Java.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит и чем отличаются схемы от баз данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root@host# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:*******
mysql> use TUTORIALS;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE tutorials_tbl(
   -> tutorial_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   -> tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   -> tutorial_author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   -> submission_date DATE,
   -> PRIMARY KEY ( tutorial_id )
   -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
mysql>
```

Пример упер с просторов интернета. Что происходит?

1. Запускаем клиента mysql под пользователем `root`, авторизация по паролю
2. Переключаемся на базу данных `TUTORIALS`
3. Создаем в ней таблицу `tutorials_tbl` с указанными столбцами и индексом.
   Легко адаптировать пример под ваши нужды